# Automatically lock my computer when I walk away from it

Tags: bluetooth, security, lock-screen

I would like to lock my Ubuntu after I walk away from it. Ideally, it should be a small Bluetooth tag / card that I carry in my pocket with a proximity sensor.

Is there some software and hardware that I can use for Linux for this purpose?

Basically, I'm looking for something like GateKeeper (*but I don't know if this works for Linux*) https://technabob.com/blog/2014/03/19/gatekeeper-locks-pc-automatically/

> The proximity feature will automatically lock and unlock your PC or Mac when you walk away from it. That will keep your machine from sitting unprotected.

Comment: Hello. Sorry this is not the place to be sourcing hardware devices.  Try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What about the software part of it?

Comment: You would need the hardware first. They are probably sold together IF it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question at the top of my google search for the same concern, and I thought I'll put in a proper answer for the benefit of others who end up here the same way I did.

Apparently there is a software called BlueProximity https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/use-bluetooth-phone-unlock-ubuntu that doesn't need any new hardware, but can just use your phone as the bt device to check if you're around or not.

There's also https://github.com/LethalEthan/Bluetooth-Unlock that does a similar thing.

Comment: Doesn't exist in Ubuntu since 18.04 (Bionic)